# how to imagine the logic of the interrupt setting for timer DAC in cubemc STM32

Tags: embedded

In my manual the DAC settings on one hand we set the trigger out event,So my logic says its using an interrupt.
but they uncheck the NVIC option as shown bellow.
So i cant see how these two play together.
I cant see the trigger interrupt logic of how this thing is going to run.
Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Would you describe what is it that you are trying to do or achieve? Do you want to trigger DAC with a timer, or have an interrupt from timer? Trigger does not mean interrupt and interrupt does not mean trigger.

Comment: Events are not the same as interrupts. The NVIC triggers on an event. You could also poll for the event in for example, a while loop. The event is just a flag, the NVIC handles the interrupt service routine.